# Upcoming movie about an android

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

At some point in the last year, I saw a preview for a movie at the theater.  What I remember is a person dressed in a hoodie walking into a private bathroom at a gas station or something.  The impression is that this person is on the lam, hiding.  After our hero gets in the bathroom, the hood goes back and it's clearly not human, but behaving like one.  We hear heavy breathing and the android is looking at its arms and body, clearly suffering from severe dysmorphia (human woken up in a robot body.)

I cannot for the life of me remember the movie title nor find it in any upcoming movies list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like [**The Prototype**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2223842/):

> [image: Prototype] <sup>[Source](http://newblockbusters.com/the-prototype-2013-official-teaser-trailer/)</sup>
>
> The military tries to track down a humanoid drone that escapes from a government facility

- [Watch the trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1p0_R8ZLB0)